Ad Hoc Apple Distribution with flutter
I used Ad Hoc used iOS DISTRIBUTION from this youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZkPa0Ef6ZI&t=132s
Is work but, when I install on 2 iPhone, say me "Developer mode is required - To run, you need to enable developer mode, until you have activated it, the app will not be available for use"
Screenshot
I want the app can install and use without use APP STORE and without enable developer mode, as "internal tests" present on GOOGLE PLAY, mean that they can install app and use without the expiration date.
If I use TESTFLIGHT, the app can use for 60 days and after, I renew and update only the version number.
Example go to SUSHI RESTAURANT, there are iPad on tables with the app to order food, this app isn't publish on App Store.
How is possible install app without use TESTFLIGHT?
How does it work?
How do you make the app installable without the App Store and TestFlight?
Install and use app without APP STORE and is private

Hi, I have the same problem you describe.
(Apple Distribution certificate, Ad-Hoc provisioning profile, UDID(s) registered)
Did you manage to solve it somehow? Thank you for any info :)
